# Displaying Django model field in template

Tags: python, django

Sorry if this is duplicate, I've found a lot of scattered info on this, but not sure how to put this together.

In my model I have:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    technology = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    webbody = models.TextField()
        # models.FileField(upload_to='webcontent/projects')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/projects')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I can type HTML in webbody and display it in the template using admin no problem:

```
{{project.webbody | safe}}
```

But what I originally had was instead of a TextField, the commented line with filefield. I can upload the file through admin and that works nicely, but for the love of me I can't then display it in the template.

I tried:

```
{{project.webbody.url}}
{% include project.webbody %}
```

How does one properly handles external HTML files in django templates?

EDIT: I added a summernote to the admin so I can edit HTML inside of admin, which is actually much better than my original idea, but still - the question stands thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the file.

This is what you can do in your view:

```py
def myview(request):
    project = Project.objects.get()
    content = open(project.webbody.path).read()
    return render(
        request, 'mytemplate.html', {
            'project': project,
            'content': content,
        }
    )
```

You can read more about how to store files in Django [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/files/).

Comment: Thanks! I totally missed that, I was on this page before ;)

Comment: You’re welcome. :) Please accept my answer if it helped you. :)

Comment: Just gonna test it and I shall. I would buy you a beer even if it doesn't work though! ;)